# Single "jq" command write to different files

Tags: json, jq

I have a JSON log file, `test.log`:

```json
{"type":"1","fname":"AAA","lname":"bbb" }    
{"type":"2","state":"gujarat" }     
{"type":"3","city":"ahmedabad" }    
{"type":"3","city":"rajkot" }   
{"type":"1","fname":"ccc","lname":"ddd" }
```

I run the following commands

```bash
cat test.log | jq -c "select(.type==\"1\")|{fname:.fname}" > type_1.txt     
cat test.log | jq -c "select(.type==\"3\")|{city:.city}" > type_3.txt
```

Is it possible for a single `jq` command to generate multiple output files?

I want to run the `jq` command only one time on the `test.log` file and generate an output file for each item type.

Comment: As far as I know, jq can't even write one file by itself... With extra assumptions (e.g., the input is much larger than the output), one could arrange something to keep and tag both types you are interested it, and filter them subsequently into two files.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the IO section of the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#IO) as of version 1.5 jq can only write to the standard output and print debug messages to `stderr`.

What you could do if you don't want to run jq on `test.log` multiple times, e.g, because it is a huge file, is

```
jq -c '(select(.type=="1") | {fname:.fname}), (select(.type=="3") | {city:.city})' test.log > temp
# The file 'temp' contains one entry per line.
grep '^{"fname"' temp > type_1.txt
grep '^{"city"' temp > type_3.txt   
rm temp
```

Answer (score 2):

Not with `jq`, but with another JSON-aware processor, Miller (`mlr`),

```bash
mlr --json put -q '
    $type == 1 { emit >"type_1.txt", { "fname": $fname } }
    $type == 3 { emit >"type_3.txt", { "city":  $city  } }' file
```

This prints a JSON object containing an `fname` key and the corresponding value to the file `type_1.txt` if the `type` is `1`, and likewise processes the `type` `3` entries for the `city` key.

If the files `type_1.txt` and `type_3.txt` exists, they will be truncated (emptied) before this command writes new data to them.

Example run:

```bash
$ mlr --json put -q '$type == 1 { emit >"type_1.txt", { "fname": $fname } }; $type == 3 { emit >"type_3.txt", { "city":  $city  } }' file
$ cat type_1.txt
{ "fname": "AAA" }
{ "fname": "ccc" }
$ cat type_3.txt
{ "city": "ahmedabad" }
{ "city": "rajkot" }
```

Answer (score 1):

`jq` only writes to stdout (or stderr), so you need another program for splitting the stream into different logfiles.
First you enrich the `js` command of @nwk with a logfile field.

```
jq -c '(select(.type=="1") | {"logfile":.type},{fname:.fname}),
       (select(.type=="3") | {"logfile":.type},{city:.city})' test.log
```

You can pipe this output to `awk`, that can pick up the filenames

```
jq -c '(select(.type=="1") | {"logfile":.type},{fname:.fname}),
       (select(.type=="3") | {"logfile":.type},{city:.city})' test.log |
       awk -F"\"" 'BEGIN {FPAT="[^{}:\"]+" } 
            $1=="logfile" {lf="type_"$2".txt"; next}
            {print >> lf}'
```

Comment: This seems to be the only actual answer of the question, but your suggestion is unnecessary complex since you shoehorn `awk` into parsing JSON instead of columnar data which it does best. A much simpler way would be `jq -r '(select(.type=="1") | "type_1.txt\t\({fname})"), (select(.type=="3") | "type_3.txt\t\({city})")' text.log | awk '{print $2 >$1}'`.

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to use a full-blown language here. Like:

```
perl -MJSON -ne '
  BEGIN{$j = JSON->new}
  $j->incr_parse($_);
  END{
    for $i ($j->incr_parse) {
      $t = delete($i->{type});
      $out{$t} .= to_json($i) . "\n";
    }
    for $t (keys %out) {
      open OUT, ">", "type_$t.json" or die "type_$t.json: $!\n";
      print OUT $out{$t};
    }
  }' < input.json
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party. You can flip this problem on its head. Instead of asking how to make `jq` write to different files, you can instead make `jq` create output that, when run as a script, writes to different files.

Here's an example:

```
jq -r \
  $' recurse( .children[] ) | 
  select( (.type="comment") and (.text != null) ) |
  "echo \'" + .text + "\' >> " + .author + ".txt" ' < file.json
```

When run, this produces output such as:

```
echo '<p>Nice! Definitely let me know.</p>' >> user_1.txt
echo '<p>I agree.</p>' >> user_2.txt
```

That output can then be run as a script to create the separate files. No dependencies beyond `jq` and the current shell, no piping, and no additional tools are needed. Note the `$'` prefix and `'` suffix allow escaping `\'` within the `echo` statement.

Answer (score 0):

I came here looking for a quick answer but I didn't like any of these because I didn't like the idea that I had to make a separate query for each file.

You can use the `select` option from `jq` with some nix to split the json into separate files.

```
jq -r '.type' test.log | uniq | xargs -i bash -c "jq '. | select( .type==\"{}\" )' test.log > \"{}.json\""
```

Explained:

- Use `jq` to get all the fields that you want to create files for
- `uniq` makes the list unique
- `xargs` that list
- `bash -c` so you can redirect each call to `jq` to its own file
- Use `jq` again to select from the original log file only those parts of the data you want and write it to its own file.

This essentially automates the process of calling `jq` on the file multiple times

Comment: Thanks Martin, this is the best way in my opinion.

Comment: just noticed, uniq is not sufficient as the output need not be sorted, hence use sort -u instead.

jq -r '.type' test.log | sort -u | xargs ....

Comment: there is a typo in teh xargs also,
xargs -I{} so that the {} inside the bash command string gets substituted.

Comment: I think we must have been using different nix distros (I use Ubuntu mostly). `xargs -i` is equivalent to `xargs -I{}` though the former has been deprecated for some time. Similar `uniq` and `sort -u` are equivalent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22287871/what-is-the-difference-between-sort-u-and-uniq.

Comment: As it happens I could improve this answer by removing the pipe to `uniq` and using `jq` for that e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822622/get-all-unique-json-key-names-with-jq `jq` is an awesome tool but I often forget how much more power it has and/or lack the skills to put that power to good use.

Comment: ah, I thought -i was wrongly placed instead of the capital one!.  yes, you are right.

Comment: yes, using the jq itself to sort and uniq is a good idea.  but uniq expects its input to be sorted, so it is not strictly same as sort -u.